# how to configure access-point through c# code

Tags: c#, snmp, mib, access-point

I usually do the network settings of the access point through a web-browser with the address 192.168.0.254 with Username and Password = admin.

The access point has a remote facility using SNMPv1/v2 agent with MIB-II.

My question: Is possible to configure the access point through c# desktop? Where I can obtain a reference about SNMPv1/v2 agent with MIB-II?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to configure the access point through c# desktop?

Yes, login to your Access-point through your web browser 192.168.0.254 then **enable SNMP Agent**. Look at [here](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?page_id=171) great resource about SNMP.